# Open Graph error on submission - publishing a stream story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, stream, publish

Can you spot my error?

I'm really struggling to get an open graph action approved. I want people to Share (Action) a Photo (Object) and have requested the user message and explicitly shared functions. The latest comment I have had back from Facebook is this:

> We are unable to test this action due to an error within your app.
>   Please make sure that your action functions correctly by testing with
>   the Auth Dialog Preview User and re-submit.

Not very helpful!

I have tested my action with the Auth Dialog Preview User and it worked fine. I have also tested my page with the object debugger which returned the response code 200 - which apparently means all is fine (is that correct?).

Below is the code I am using on my test page and was hoping someone would be able to point out where my errors are as I can't see it:

```
<head>
meta tags here

<script type="text/javascript">
  function Share()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/NAMESPACE:share&photo=TEST PAGE URL&message=Cool photos&fb:explicitly_shared=true&access_token=ACCESS TOKEN','POST',  function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
              } else {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
              }
        });
    }
  </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 1180 });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));

      // Init the SDK upon load
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'APP ID', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//CHANNEL FILE URL', // Path to your Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
          oauth      :true
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
            FB.api('/me', function(me){
              if (me.name) {
                document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
              }
            })
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
          }
        });

        // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
        document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
          FB.login();
        });
        document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
          FB.logout();
        }); 
      } 

      function loginUser() {    
     FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'publish_actions, email'});     
     }
    </script>

 <div id="auth-status">
        <div id="auth-loggedout">
          <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink"><img src="login_btn.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display:none">

      </div>
    </div>

<form>
    <input class="shr-btn" type="button" value="" onClick="Share()" />
  </form>

</body>
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

D

---

Aaarrggh. I've now had this response from Facebook:

> Your code is currently configured to publish a stream story. You must
>   change your code so that when the test user triggers the action it
>   produces an open graph story. Please make the appropriate changes and
>   resubmit.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? I thought the code was set up to publish an open graph story - but apparently now.

If someone could point out what I am doing wrong I would be eternally grateful.

Many thanks.

D

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have more to do with how you're passing in the additional parameters in this line:

```
'/me/NAMESPACE:share&photo=TEST PAGE URL&message=Cool photos&
fb:explicitly_shared=true&access_token=ACCESS TOKEN','POST',  function(response)
```

You really want to do something more like:

```
FB.api('/me/NAMESPACE:share', 'post', 
{ photo : 'TEST_PAGEURL', message : 'Cool photos' }, function(response));
```

The important thing here is to include your custom JSON content as the third parameter to the function.  It seems like the URL parameters method might be triggering that sort of message, since it's an older implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response Critical Sass. The problem turned out to be that I was trying to use the term 'share' as an open graph action. I presume Share is a term associated with a stream story rather than open graph. I don't know why they couldn't have just pointed this out though!

Comment: From what I've seen, share is actually a *default* Open Graph action link, along with *like* & *comment* - that's probably why!

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not because you are creating a story using the verb "share." I just got a story approved by Facebook where I used the verb "share." And my story was rejected earlier for the same reason as yours.

Basically you cannot post something to an album or any other kind of post when you are using an open graph story. For example the following is not allowed:

```
                $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);//disallowed                
                $facebook->api(
                  'me/invig-test:share',
                  'POST',
                  array(
                        'app_id' => $configParam['appId'],
                        'type' => "test:photo",
                        'photo' => "http://samples.ogp.me/574859819237737",                   
                        'title' => "a photo",
                        'image[0][url]'=>"http://www.testapp.com/".$imgFile,
                        'image[0][user_generated]'=>'true',
                        'message' => $comments,                   
                        'fb:explicitly_shared'=>true,
                    )
                  );
```

Instead only do the "share":

```
                $facebook->api(
                  'me/invig-test:share',
                  'POST',
                  array(
                        'app_id' => $configParam['appId'],
                        'type' => "test:photo",
                        'photo' => "http://samples.ogp.me/574859819237737",                   
                        'title' => "a photo",
                        'image[0][url]'=>"http://www.testapp.com/".$imgFile,
                        'image[0][user_generated]'=>'true',
                        'message' => $comments,                   
                        'fb:explicitly_shared'=>true,
                    )
                  );
```